# Getting Data inside a fragment from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working with Android `Fragment`s pretty extensively and one of the problems I am having is the lack of proper mechanism to pass complex objects to it.

In the android developers documentation for `Fragments`, they have a `static` method called `newInstance` called with some simple arguments which will be packaged into a `Bundle` and used inside the `Fragment`. However this method cannot be employed for passing complex objects.

Because I have been using the Fragments api a lot, it is becoming more and more important to have complex objects passed to it. One way to do this is by implementing the `Parcelable` interface, which I don't want to do for all the classes.

So, I thought I could do this :

- Define an interface like this in the Fragment:

```
// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface ReceiveDataInterface {
  public MyClass getData(uniqueFragmentID);
}
```

Force the Activities using this fragment to implement the interface and call `ReceiveDataInterface.getData(getArgument.getString(UNIQUEID))`

- In the `Activity` instantiate fragment using the `newInstance` method by passing a `uniqueFragmentID` and implement the `ReceiveDataInterface` which gives data based on `uniqueFragmentID`.

Is it a good idea to do this? if not, why? and how should I go about doing this?

Note:This is done in the same lines as `OnArticleSelectedListener` described in the documentation.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: if you don't want to create a parcelable, your approach looks ok to me. i don't find any thing wrong in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use this approach for any app we build for android. It works well. I havent tested every method of doing this, but i think this is among the best way.

Comment: this approach seems to be fine. But what if multiple instances of fragments are instantiated? How will an activity keep track of which fragment is seeking the data?

Comment: Then you pass a unique id like you mentioned in your question. This approach works well for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to make the Fragment themselves independent. Why not write the code that fetches data from network/database in the Fragment itself?